# Test a simple function with jest

Tags: jestjs

I want to test one simple function with Jest :

```
// src > filterByTerm.js
function filterByTerm(inputArr, searchTerm) {
    if (!searchTerm) throw Error("searchTerm cannot be empty");
    if (!inputArr.length) throw Error("inputArr cannot be empty"); // new line

    const regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, "i");
    return inputArr.filter(function(arrayElement) {
      return arrayElement.url.match(regex);
    });
 }
 module.exports = filterByTerm;

 // filterByTerm.spec.js

const filterByTerm = require("../src/filterByTerm");

describe("Filter function", () => {

   test("it should output error", () => {
        const input = [
          { id: 1, url: "https://www.url1.dev" },
          { id: 2, url: "https://www.url2.dev" },
          { id: 3, url: "https://www.link3.dev" }
        ];
        expect(filterByTerm(input, "")).toThrowError();
      });
 });
```

My Question is, why this test not passing? how to catch error from Jest ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your expect function in another function call:

Instead of:

```
expect(filterByTerm(input, "")).toThrowError(errorMessage);
```

Try:

```
expect(() => filterByTerm(input, "")).toThrow(errorMessage);
```

where errorMessage is whatever Error you're throwing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should do

```
if (!searchTerm) throw new Error("searchTerm cannot be empty");
```

and

```
expect(filterByTerm(input, "")).toThrowError("searchTerm cannot be empty");
```

You can further read [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror).

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the function so try something like this;

`const output = [{id: 3, url: "https://www.link3.dev"}];
    expect(() => {
      input('');
    }).toThrow(Error);`

and alter the function to this;

```
if (!searchTerm) throw Error("searchTerm cannot be empty");


if (!inputArr.length) throw Error("inputArr cannot be empty");
```